# How to compute value in tasks tracker or any other tracker in tuleap

Tags: tuleap

how do i add a custom field (Effort spent) in a tracker and  calculate Effort Remaining hours (field) by the formula [Estimated Effort] - [Effort spent ] = Remaining Effort (hours)

Answer (score 0):

That is not currently possible. As a side note, if the initial effort is an estimation then the effort spent rarely allows you to know how much is remaining unless the people dong it are perfectly efficient

Comment: Saying something isn't possible can be the right answer, but that, alone, leaves a question of whether you're correct or just don't know the solution. This kind of answer is always better if you can cite a source.